# Bitnami WordPress for OSX: Install in Root Directory

Tags: wordpress, directory, bitnami

Using Bitnami WordPress installer, I want to install WordPress in the root directory, instead of /wordpress directory.

(Or rather, move the WordPress website to the root directory after the installation.)

I attempted to follow somewhat dated instructions I found here:

http://bitnami.com/forums/forums/wordpress/topics/installing-to-root-folder-not-sub-folder

But I couldn't even complete the very first step because URL settings are grayed-out in the Settings panel. Also, the DocumentRoot value is very different from what is described. I think it's because the WordPress has greatly changed since 2010.

Could someone knowledgeable please help with this?

Comment: is there a good reason you want to do that? It sounds much easier to just go with what the installer gives you.

Comment: Yes there is, otherwise I would not be asking the question on this highly respected forum. Would be grateful for your advice, Mike.

Comment: then please add that reason to the question. Without it, this question doesn't make sense, since you shouldn't care about the directory structure of the WP install; it's not going to affect your life in any way. It basically sounds like you're asking an XY question right now. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress hasn't changed much since it was initially released 10 years ago or whenever it was.

**Currently:** Wordpress is installed in var/www/html/wordpress/[all the wp files are in this folder]
**You want:** Wordpress to be installed var/www/html/[all the wp files are in this folder]

1: Via ssh or ftp copy the files
    **From:** `var/www/html/wordpress`   **To:** `var/www/html`

2: In phpmyadmin > wp_options > first row > remove `wordpress` from the url.
3: there is another entry of the url on the second page of the wp_options table. Change the url there too.